# AMPScript Look up values "Start" and "Finish" dates depending on which Step of the process

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

In my data extension I have fields for "start date", "end date" and "course's unit" (being 1, 2 or 3 depending on the number of classes for each course).

For each student, I'll have different rows with the start and end date of each unit they have to fulfill.

Something like that :

| Student ID | StartDate | EndDate | Unit | Course |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 15/04/23 | 16/04/2023 | 1 | Maths |
| 12345 | 22/04/23 | 23/04/2023 | 2 | Maths |
| 12345 | 27/04/23 | 28/04/2023 | 3 | Maths |

One course, one student, different dates depending on the unit they are at.

I need to be able to have in a summary email the dates of all the units depending on the course.

I read a few guides on these functions but none were similar to my issue so I don't know where to start. I'm really new to Lookup and Lookuprow, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have a separate DE for sending, and your course DE in your post would be used to look up the dates.

So the send DE needs to link with the course DE through the "Student ID" field and because I don't know the exact context in your case, so my assumption is "Student ID" field is storing subscriber keys.

The rest is that you need to use the [LookupRows function](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/) to render all rows matching the Subscriber Key. I put an example block code here:

```
%%[
set @Subkey = AttributeValue("Your send DE subkey column")
set @data = LookupRows("Your course DE name", "Student ID", @Subkey)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@data)
if @rowCount > 0 then

]%%

Hi. Hope you are doing well. You have registered these courses:

%%[

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    set @row = row(@data, @i)
    set @Course = field(@row,"Course")
    set @Unit = field(@row,"Unit")
    set @StartDate = field(@row,"StartDate")
    set @EndDate = field(@row,"EndDate")

]%%
    <br>
    <br>%%=v(@Course)=%% Unit %%=v(@Unit)=%%:
    <br>Start date: %%=v(@StartDate)=%%
    <br>End date: %%=v(@EndDate)=%%

%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

You haven't registered any courses. Please check out our latest courses.

%%[ endif ]%%
```